# Recurring Messages when using Toast with an Intent Service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler, android-intentservice, android-looper

I am working on displaying an Android Toast message from an IntentService. After a bit of research and understanding how Loopers, Handlers and Message queues work, I implemented the solution found here: [Toast on an IntentService](http://icantrap.github.io/2014/01/19/toast-on-an-intentservice/)

I find that in addition to the latest toast, the previous toast messages are displayed in order. Can anyone explain what is happening and how to resolve this?

```
private static void toast(final Context context, final String message, final int duration){
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toastMsg = Toast.makeText(context, message , duration);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thank you, I have added the implementation

Comment: perhaps make Toast toastMsg as global (outside of the function toast) and check if toast is not null you can call toastMsg.cancel() before showing a new toast message

Comment: unfortunately, that too did not work. BTW the code is related to Udacity's StockHawk project: https://github.com/udacity/StockHawk.

Comment: https://discussions.udacity.com/t/stock-hawk-revamped-code-invalid-stock-symbol-issue/223292

Comment: you are not calling `show()` on toast anywhere

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not show that in the code but I am. Thanks.